# Why do material-ui modules show in both node_modules and src after Webpack 4 tree shaking?

Tags: webpack, lodash, material-ui, webpack-4, tree-shaking

The Cloud Native Interactive Landscape is an open-source, browser-only application that loads a static React app for visualizing the cloud native ecosystem:

- Try the [app](https://landscape.cncf.io/)
- View [source](https://github.com/cncf/landscape/)

You can interactively view the [results](https://landscape.cncf.io/report.html) of webpack-bundle-analyzer and here is a snapshot:

[image: Webpack Bundle Analyzer image]

I don't understand why `@material-ui/core/es` appears in both `node_modules` and `src`. More generally, I'm trying to understand if our tree-shaking is optimally implemented, or if there's a better way to configure it. I would also appreciate hearing if we're optimally tree-shaking lodash. (Note that we're only targeting evergreen browsers.)

Please feel free to fork the [repo](https://github.com/cncf/landscape/) and edit [webpack.config.prod.js](https://github.com/cncf/landscape/blob/master/webpack.config.prod.js). If you open a pull request, Netlify will build and deploy a test server and you can check for results under *test-server-url*`/report.html`.

Comment: It seems a webpack bundle analyzer issue. See this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer/issues/161

Comment: wow what a grand perspectif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me preface that the `es` name was poorly chosen. `src` would be much more fitting since it's just that: The untranspiled source code. This is documented in [the docs under minimizing bundlesize](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#ecmascript)

With webpack 4 and proper `module` entries in the respective `package.json` you should automatically pull in the esmodule version of those packages. The esmodule version is responsible for most of the tree-shaking optimization in webpack.

`@material-ui/core` already has a proper entry. This is however only at the top level an esmodule version. The actual components are then written with commonJS which does not allow tree-shaking in webpack. We have an [open PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/13391) but we might wait for the next major since we don't test on the compiled files which makes changes to the build scary.

As to why this appears as a concatenated module I can't help you with that. While investigating I made the same observation (https://github.com/eps1lon/material-ui-treeshaking). It is probably an issue with the bundle-analyzer and has no actual impact on the generated chunks (e.g. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer/issues/188).

Overall I would recommend not using the `es` version and simply letting webpack target the `module` entry. It allows tree shaking for the bulk of the package but you loose out on some micro-optimization. I tested transpiling everything to esmodules and made some improvements to the stat size of a bundle from 200KB to 180KB but hit some gzip deoptimization which increased the gzipped size by 1KB ([meme version](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11281#issuecomment-433004122)). So don't stress about tree-shaking for every tiny file.

Comment: I appreciate the links as well as your contributions to material-ui. I edited to mention that we're only targeting evergreen browsers so I think we want the `es` version.